# Как сделать приложение, которое запустится на андроиде 2.2 без установщика и откроет веб-страницу?

Tags: android, автозагрузка

Подскажите, пожалуйста,
Как сделать приложение, которое запустится на андроиде 2.2 без установщика и откроет веб-страницу? Приложение запускается, но веб-страница не открывается, потому что при автозапуске не были установлены разрешения на доступ в сеть. Обычно пользователи его ставят вручную когда работает установщик программ. А как быть, если это нужно сделать автоматически?

Answer (score 1):

Разрешения выставляются не пользователями при установке, а программистом в манифесте (AndroidManifest.xml)  
И дальше, если приложение установлено, то у него будут все разрешения, которые запрошены(прописаны) в манифесте.

Answer (score -1):

Почитайте про phonegap, этот движок на похожих принципах и работает, может подойдет.